# Is $f=t^5 + t^4 + 1$ reducible or irreducible over the field of $Z_2$ integers modulo 2.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I need to find out whether $f=t^5 + t^4 + 1$ is reducible or irreducible over the field of $Z_2$ integers modulo 2. I approached the question by substituting 0 and 1 into the function and got answers which were not equal to 0. Hence I assumed that the function is irreducible over the field of $Z_2$ integers modulo 2, because it does not have a root. Is this approach and answer right?

Comment: Showing a polynomial has no roots just shows it has no linear factors.  This polynomial could still factor as a cubic and a quadratic.  But there aren't very many irreducibles of degrees $2$ and $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so you should be able to check.

Comment: @abiessue Do i have to check that f is not divisible by all irreducible polynomials of degree 2 or just one of them?

Comment: @SpamIAm Do i have to check that f is not divisible by all irreducible polynomials of degree 2 or degree 3?

Comment: Since it has no roots, if it is reducible it is of the form $g(t)h(t)$ where $g(t)=t^2+at+b$ and $h(t)=t^3+ct^2+dt+e$. Now find a contradiction in the system of equations. You should also think about it is possible to assume that $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are monic.

Comment: *why it is possible

Comment: @GitGud What does monic mean?

Comment: See [monic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial).

Comment: @Jnyeboah93 Yes, you have to check for all of them.  But $t^2 + t + 1$ is the only irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{Z}_2[t]$.  Can you see why?  Once you've shown that, it actually suffices to check that $t^2 + t + 1$ doesn't divide the given polynomial to show it's irreducible.